# Show Desktop button too quick in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop

Somewhere along the line, some PC performance app altered how the "Show Desktop" button in the bottom-right of Windows 7 works. By default, it takes a second to activate when you hover over it. But now, the exact moment I hover over it, the screen goes blank, and it's quite annoying.

The tool(s) which most likely did this was Advanced System Care (and its multiple additional apps). I'm guessing there may be a registry setting somewhere I can tweak to fix this.

How can I revert this particular setting so that the desktop doesn't show the exact second I hover over the "Show Desktop" button in the bottom-right of my screen?

Comment: "How can I revert this particular setting " - Use Windows' "System Restore", that's what it's for.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 For people who are afraid to do things like change registry entries, not to revert one tiny little setting.

Comment: Plus I only use system restore if something's corrupted. This is just one particular setting. It's highly illogical to revert to a restore point just to fix one setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable editing your registry, the relevant key should be `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\DesktopLivePreviewHoverTime`. The value is in milliseconds.

Relevant information was found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5473/make-aero-peek-display-instantly-or-disable-it-in-windows-7/).

As and31415 points out, the key can simply be deleted to restore the setting to the default.

After changing the setting explorer will need to be restarted. This is done most easily by logging out and back in.

Comment: Awesome, and I'm assuming it also requires a restart of Explorer.exe to apply the changes. Unless there's a Windows API call or message I could call to apply the change?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to restart explorer. You can log off and back on, or there's always the option of killing explorer and restarting it from the task manager.

Comment: @JerryDodge As the value doesn't exist by default, you can also restore the original time delay by deleting the `DesktopLivePreviewHoverTime` registry value.